# How to get light swish/trail effect in aftereffects?

Tags: after-effects

Ok Im trying to emulate light path effects in aftereffects like this at this point (the weapon swing): https://youtu.be/6gX-dCaLCo0?t=66

I saw this tutorial, however it only works on windows: https://youtu.be/HxyGDekCGEs

How can I create the light glow/trail effect here in AE?

Comment: Trapcode particular is available for Mac, too. What about that tutorial was windows specific? One of my biggest gripes with after effects is that 99% of the time you see something cool done with it, it’s always a third-party plug-in doing the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 2):

One option without using any 3rd party plugins is to track the motion of the object you want to leave a trail, apply that motion to a shape layer, then apply an echo effect to it. Additional effects like glow, and motion blur (all native effects), and playing with transfer modes and opacity will help sell it.